# openssl 3.3 not read RC2-40-CBC

Tags: ubuntu, openssl

I need to use the openssl 1.1.1 version on ubuntu 22.4
From what I've read it seems not to be possible since ubuntu 22.4 defaults to openssl 3.0 version
The reason for this need lies in a .p12 file that uses the RC2-40-CBC algorithm which turns out not to be read by openssl version 3.3. Has anyone managed to solve?

Comment: There is no OpenSSL 3.3; 3.1 was only released a few days ago. 3.0 (which has been out over a year and is used in Ubuntu22.04) up by default does not support obsolete algorithms like RC2. **For commandline, offtopic for SO, use `-provider legacy`** or on the `pkcs12` command simply `-legacy`. Code would be ontopic but varies; show your MVCE.

Comment: Can you tell me which command line I have to use to enable the algorithm to a .p12 file?